# Why everytime I click on delete chat message the app stop working?

Tags: android, chat, message

Every time when I click on delete chat message, the app will stop working. I did check back the code based on the errors I got but I'm still not sure what's wrong with the code.

```java
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

          case R.id.action_delete:
             getContentResolver().delete(Uri.withAppendedPath(ContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_MESSAGES_CHAT, profileChatId), null, null);
             getContentResolver().delete(Uri.withAppendedPath(ContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_PROFILE, profileId), null, null);                    
             finish();

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
```

Below is my chat menu layout.

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

      <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:title="@string/delete_chat"/>


</menu>
```

These are the errors I get.

```js
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported URI: content://com.example.app.provider/messages/chat/
            at com.example.app.DataProvider.delete(DataProvider.java:189)
            at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.delete(ContentProvider.java:273)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1282)
            at com.example.app.ChatActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(ChatActivity.java:158)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:350)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:742)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:881)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:546)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Data Provider.java

```js
@Override
 public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  
  int count;
  switch(uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
  case MESSAGES_ALLROWS:
   count = db.delete(TABLE_MESSAGES, selection, selectionArgs);
   break;   
   
  case MESSAGES_SINGLE_ROW:
   count = db.delete(TABLE_MESSAGES, "_id = ?", new String[]{uri.getLastPathSegment()});
   break;

  case PROFILE_ALLROWS:
   count = db.delete(TABLE_PROFILE, selection, selectionArgs);
   break;   
   
  case PROFILE_SINGLE_ROW:
   count = db.delete(TABLE_PROFILE, "_id = ?", new String[]{uri.getLastPathSegment()});
   break;
   
  case MESSAGES_CHAT_ROW:
   count = db.delete(TABLE_MESSAGES, "to_cid = ? or ( from_cid = ? and to_cid = ?)", new String[]{uri.getLastPathSegment(),uri.getLastPathSegment(), Common.getChatId()});
   Log.d("count del", ""+count);
   break;
   
  default:
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);   
  }
        ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
        cr.notifyChange(uri, null);

  return count;
 }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @cyroxis I already add in the errors in the post.

Comment: Hello...anybody knows how to solve it?

Comment: Where is getContentResolve()? What does it return?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just add in the Data Provider.java. Is this the info you are asking?

Comment: It appears you are not sending a valid URI

Comment: You mean the problem occurs in the "getContentResolver() of case R.id.action_delete"? May I know how should I correct it?